# Spit up date after converting it to a string

Tags: javascript

I have a date in milliseconds that I convert to a readable date.  Then I covert it to a string so I can split it up and break it down to use the parts I need.  The problem is when I break it down by space, it breaks down each character by itself and does not split it up where there's a space.  Can anybody explain why and what I'm doing wrong?

here's my code:

```
var formattedDate = new Date(somedateMS);

var formattedDateSplit = formattedDate.toString();

formattedDateSplit.split(" ");

console.log(formattedDateSplit);  // Mon May 18 2015 18:35:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
console.log(formattedDateSplit[0]); // M
console.log(formattedDateSplit[1]); // o
console.log(formattedDateSplit[2]); // n
console.log(formattedDateSplit[3]); // [space]
console.log(formattedDateSplit[4]); // M
console.log(formattedDateSplit[5]); // a
console.log(formattedDateSplit[6]); // y
```

How can I split it up so I can get rid of the day of the week, and just have the May 18 2015 18:35:27 into 4 separate values? (May, 18, 2015, 18:35:27)?

I've done this before and not sure why this time it's splitting it up by character.

Thank you!

Comment: You never assigned the result of `.split()` to a variable.

Comment: Especially since you say "You've done this before", try and use a much more compliant library like moment.js for date ops like these. Shall make life easier, trust me!

Comment: Barmar - Sorry that was a typo.  Fixed it now
bParatik - This is for a Chrome extension so I'm trying to keep the 3rd party libraries to a minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting `formattedDateSplit` to the whole Date string, unsplit:

```
var formattedDateSplit = formattedDate.toString();
```

Then you do this, which is probably a typo:

```
formattedSplit.split(" ");
```

since that's the wrong variable name; what you *probably* meant was:

```
formattedDateSplit = formattedDateSplit.split(" ");
```

You're getting individual characters because the subsequent code is just indexing into the string itself, not the split-up version of the string. The `.split()` function returns the array, so you have to assign it to something; it does not modify the string.

Comment: `formattedDateSplit = formattedDateSplit.split(" ");` was my problem!  Thank you for the great explanation!  Learned something new today (the single chars that is)